# Contact Form 7 plugin submit button

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to change the submit button style of contact form 7. https://www.narwal.shop/contact-us/

- Change background colour
- Add border radius 2 px
- Add hover white background colour, black font and black border

Normaly I find the source and edit the CSS file, however this no impact. Do you know which file I have to edit?

[Click here for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PllHV.png)

Comment: Just add a class to your submit button and customize it - https://contactform7.com/submit-button/

Comment: you can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-style/ this plugins for change all style of contact form 7

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
input#cntctbttn {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

and add it in appearance -> style editor(style.css))

Answer (score 1):

The style-settings from `#cntctbttn` seems to overwrite yours. Just search in the project for `#cntctbttn`and comment it out or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code inside your css file:

```
.wpcf7-submit:hover {
    color: black !important;
    background: white !important;
    border: 1px solid !important;
}
```

Definitely it will work.

Answer (score 0):

insert id for the submit button then use the code below:

```
input#id {
border: 1px solid #000000;
background: #caf1ff;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 2px;
}

input#id:hover {
background: #ffffff;
color: #000000;
}
```